# django deferring all fields in a related model queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a query where I need the second related model
`Model1.objects.all().select_related("model2__model3")`

but I don't need any field from model2, only many different fields from model3, e.g. `obj.model2.model3.name` and others

How can I defer all fields from model2 without explicitly mentioning them one after the other?

EDIT: Model1 has ForeignKey to Model2 that has ForeignKey to Model3

Comment: There might be a better way. What's the relationship between them?

Comment: Why not add a foreign key to `model1` that references `model3`?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica I don't think that's a problem, my answer solves it really easily

Comment: I've posted an answer below, check it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that you're trying to use the [`.only()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#only) queryset method, the below snippet should work.

As per the django docs:

> The only() method is more or less the opposite of defer(). You call it with the fields that should not be deferred when retrieving a model. If you have a model where almost all the fields need to be deferred, using only() to specify the complementary set of fields can result in simpler code.

```py
Model1.objects.all().only('model2__model3__name').select_related("model2__model3")
```

With the above snippet, trying to access any field from `model2` will result in a database access, whilst accessing `model2.model3.name` will not.

This way all fields from `model2` will be deferred. And if you want to access another field just pass it to the `.only()` function `.only('model2__model3__name', 'model2__model3__another')`.